# How do I change this code to integrate from t= 100 to 200 instead of t= 0 to 100

Tags: python

```
def roessler(xyx):
   a,b,c= (0.1,0.1,14)

   x,y,z=xyx

    dx= -y-z
    dy=x+a*y
    dz= b+z*(x-c)


    return np.array([dx, dy, dz])

def rk4(f, xyxinit, Tmax, N):
        T = np.linspace(-10,Tmax,N+1)
        xyx = np.zeros( (len(T), len(xyxinit)) )
        xyx[110] = xyxinit
        h = Tmax / N
        for i in range(N):
            k1 = f(xyx[i])
            k2 = f(xyx[i] + h/2.0*k1)
            k3 = f(xyx[i] + h/2.0*k2)
            k4 = f(xyx[i] + h*k3)
            xyx[i+1] = xyx[i] + h/6.0 *( k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
        return T, xyx

x0, y0, z0= (0, 0, 0)
initialconditions = np.array([x0,y0,z0])

`t, result = rk4(roessler, initialconditions, 100, 1000)
```

This currently integrates from 0-100 in steps of 0.1. How do I change it to t= 100-200? This is using the runge kutta code.

Comment: Are you sure about the fixed index in `xyx[110] = xyxinit`? What exactly is your goal, do you want to set the initial condition at `t=100` and integrate over `t=0..200`?